# threejs raycast click detection not working on loaded 3dObject

Tags: javascript, three.js, raycasting

I load a .obj file:

```
var loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
loader.load( "../obj/machine.obj", '../obj/machine.mtl',  this.loadObject);
```

And try to detect a click on it:

```
 click: function(event){
        this.mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
        this.mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;
        var vector = new THREE.Vector3( this.mouse.x, this.mouse.y, 1 ).unproject( this.camera );
        this.raycaster.set( this.camera.position, vector.sub( this.camera.position ).normalize() );

        console.log(this.scene.children);
        var intersects = this.raycaster.intersectObjects( this.scene.children );

        if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {

            console.log("hitting something");

        }
    },
```

This works fine on meshes but not on the loaded 3DObject while it is visible in the this.scene.childeren:

```
[THREE.Mesh, THREE.Line, THREE.PointLight, --> THREE.Object3D <-- ]0: THREE.Mesh__webglActive: true__webglInit: true_listeners: Object_modelViewMatrix: THREE.Matrix4_normalMatrix: THREE.Matrix3castShadow: falsechildren: Array[0]eulerOrder: (...)frustumCulled: truegeometry: THREE.IcosahedronGeometryid: 4material: THREE.MeshBasicMaterialmatrix: THREE.Matrix4matrixAutoUpdate: truematrixWorld: THREE.Matrix4matrixWorldNeedsUpdate: falsename: ""parent: THREE.Sceneposition: THREE.Vector3quaternion: THREE.QuaternionreceiveShadow: falserenderDepth: nullrotation: THREE.EulerrotationAutoUpdate: truescale: THREE.Vector3type: "Mesh"up: THREE.Vector3useQuaternion: (...)userData: Objectuuid: "46D85379-A9CE-4221-A599-39D13EE4CB34"visible: true__proto__: Object1: THREE.Line2: THREE.PointLight3: THREE.Object3D
```

So something tells me it needs something else for loaded 3dObjects. But I have no clue at what that could be. My idea is that the raycast looks for vertices for intersection and it wouldn't matter if that's a cube mesh or a 3dObject mesh. Does anybody has an idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass the recursive flag like so

```
var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( objects, true );
```

three.js r.69

Comment: Thank you, I could kiss you if you where here.